# Lego Wedo 2.0 projects

Tags: instructions, wedo

I am new to Lego. Got an ESM for my son when the pandemic started. Now we got a Wedo 2.0. Please suggest me any good set of project instructions or book which will help him to learn.

Comment: By ESM do you mean the [Early Simple Machines Set](https://www.lego.com/en-de/product/early-simple-machines-set-9656)? How old is your son, what do you wish to help him learn?

Comment: Yes I meant Early Simple Machines. I just want to bring out creativity in him and help him to learn thinking in a structured way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Instructions and project collections

[LEGO's own WeDo project site](https://education.lego.com/en-us/lessons/wedo-2-science) is a great starting point.

[NayaCreations' 65 projects on Brickssafe](https://bricksafe.com/pages/NayaCreations/lego-wedo-2.0)

[Daniele Benedettelli's LEGO WeDo 2.0 Archives](https://robotics.benedettelli.com/category/lego-wedo2-projects/) contains many projects, some free, some paid.

### Youtube collections

[Top 20 Wedo 2.0 in 2020 | Lego wedo projects.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TcZQYq5kik)

[22 Amazing creations by Lego Wedo 2.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJOMnWbEc80)